# Уместны ли в этом длинном предложении точки с запятой? Или на их месте должны быть запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, авторская-пунктуация, точка-с-запятой

По пути могло встретиться множество опасностей — и дикие звери, и лихие люди, которых расплодилось немало с тех пор, как итарков в наших краях не стало, а оружие, наоборот, завелось у каждого; и бездонные трясины, прикидывающиеся невинными полянками; и покинутые деревни, где, по слухам, водились мстительные неупокойники.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно предложить такой вариант оформления:

*По пути могло встретиться множество опасностей: **и дикие звери и лихие люди,** которых расплодилось немало с тех пор, как итарков в наших краях не стало, а оружие, наоборот, завелось у каждого; и бездонные трясины, прикидывающиеся невинными полянками; и покинутые деревни, где, по слухам, водились мстительные неупокойники.*

Пояснение

1. В таких предложениях бессоюзная связь обычно обозначается пояснительным двоеточием, подробно раскрывающим тему.
2. Использование точки с запятой необходимо: так мы вы выделяем  три отдельные распространенные темы в группе однородных членов, особенно при наличии собственных знаков препинания в каждой группе.
3. Вызывает сомнение только первая часть, в которую желательно включить объединенное сочетание "дикие звери и лихие люди", если это **не противоречит** смысловому содержанию.
4. Группы однородных членов соединяются повторяющимся союзом И...И.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ (о диких зверях "с оружием"):)

(1) Дикие звери и лихие люди расплодились в **одно и то же время**, которое **характерно двумя событиями**. Прежде всего, это уход итарков, которые раньше пугали зверей своим присутствием да еще, вероятно, охотились на них. А вот почему в это же время оружие стало доступным для каждого, я не совсем понимаю, поэтому и даю в ответе пометку (если это не противоречит смыслу).  Определить же это можно только по контексту.

(2) Можно, конечно, выделить зверей **в отдельную тему**, но тогда надо дать какую-то дополнительную информацию про них и поставить точку с запятой. Иначе грамматика (при постановке только запятой после первой темы) выглядит несимметрично.

Comment: Что значит ‟мы выделяем”. Это автору решать, есть ли у него замысел разбивать однородные на какие-то блоки. И еще, если перед первым однородным стоит ‟и”, то после него ставится запятая.

Comment: Смысловая группа "дикие звери и лихие люди" может не члениться запятой, если дальше говорится и о тех, и о других: "...которых расплодилось немало с тех пор..." В таком случае первый однородный член -- это "дикие звери и лихие люди...", а второй -- "и бездонные трясины...", перед которым, вы правы, должна стоять запятая (в данном случае стоит точка с запятой).

Comment: Опять же, это автору решать, разбивать ему что-то на блоки или нет,а не вам. ...Не дадут мне досмотреть Декстера.

Comment: Автору, верно. Я лишь сказал, что формально в такой пунктуации нет ошибки (хотя по смыслу есть: ведь дальше речь идёт о том, что оружие завелось у каждого -- выходит, и у диких зверей тоже :/)

Answer (score 2):

Если однородный член имеет свои запятые, то обычно он обособляется точкой с запятой, но это не обязательно. Вот пара примеров из Нац. корпуса:

> И все это вместе, без промежутка: и дикий разгул, топот трепака; и исторические рыдания заглушают плеск моря и скрип снастей. [И. А. Гончаров. Фрегат «Паллада» (1855)]
> Благодарил он за все огулом: и за то, что сподобился он таланта ― стихи писать; и за чин четырнадцатого класса; и самое главное ― за то, что он стоял сейчас рядом с Глафирой. [Е. И. Замятин. Алатырь (1914)]

После обобщающего слова ставится как двоеточие, если есть предупреждающая интонация (интонацией указывается, что далее последует перечисление), так и тире, если интонация отступления (как при пояснении, но содержащем однородные).

Также авторы могут обособлять все однородные точкой с запятой, если хотя бы один имеет свои запятые, — это по желанию. Также точка с запятой может делить однородные на блоки по желанию автора.

В итоге: ‟По пути могло встретиться множество опасностей: и дикие звери, и лихие люди, которых расплодилось немало с тех пор, как итарков в наших краях не стало, а оружие, наоборот, завелось у каждого; и бездонные трясины, прикидывающиеся невинными полянками; и покинутые деревни, где, по слухам, водились мстительные неупокойники”.

Comment: "Если однородный член имеет свои запятые, то он обособляется точкой с запятой" — можно, пожалуйста, ссылку на так сформулированное правило? А то в Нацкорпусе нетрудно и обратное  найти: "О комнате пропавшего летчика заговорили все: и бывший горский князь, а ныне трудящийся Востока гражданин Гигиенишвили, и Дуня, арендовавшая койку в комнате тети Паши, и сама тетя Паша ― торговка и горькая пьяница, и Александр Дмитриевич Суховейков прошлом камергер двора его императорского величества, которого в квартире звали просто Митричем, и прочая квартирная сошка..." (Ильф и Петров).

Comment: В первом примере однородное со своими запятыми находится в конце, поэтому его запятые не смешать с запятыми, которые разграничивают однородные. В Нац. корпусе можно что угодно найти, но есть буквально тысячи примеров, которые подтверждают обособление однородных со своими запятыми.

Comment: Лингвистика не прецедентна (вернее, не только прецедентна). Примеры сами по себе не утверждают правило, ими можно лишь его подтвердить (если оно есть). Разве не так?

Comment: Я, конечно же, ничего не понял о том, что вы имеете ввиду. Если есть тысячи примеров определенной пунктуации, то может быть проблема интерпретации, или что?

Comment: Я про то, что ваш ответ: "Если однородный член имеет свои запятые, то он обособляется точкой с запятой" -- необоснованно императивен. Оборот *может* обособляться точкой с запятой -- и тому есть примеры, но *правила* такого нет -- и это подтверждают обратные примеры. Не знаю, тысячи ли их, но и вы, полагаю, частотный анализ не проводили.

Comment: Он не просто ‟может обособляться”, — это буквально тысячи примеров (против единиц), что говорит о том, что огромная часть авторов осознанно или неосознанно руководствуется таким правилом. В Нац. корпусе можно найти примеры против любого существующего правила. Если большое количество авторов руководствуется каким-то правилом, осознанно или неосознанно, то это более весомая причина использовать это правила, чем наличие его в каком-то справочнике. В справочниках много чего нет.

Comment: Правило -- это то, что зафиксировано в справочнике. Без фиксации можно говорить максимум о тенденции. Дескриптивный принцип сам по себе не работает.

Comment: Справочники Лопатина и Розенталя уже не диктуют, а описывают существующую пунктуацию (только в некоторой мере диктуют, так как если будут иметь неправильную интерпретацию, то из-за авторитета люди начнут так писать).

Comment: Не диктуют и не описывают, а кодифицируют. То есть пресуществляют тенденции в правила (или не пресуществляют, если какие-то из тенденций не соответствуют законам языка). Я не намерен вдаваться в основы лингвистики, возвращусь к началу: считаю неуместным ваши императивные ответы, основанные на личных, никакими трудами не подкреплённых исследованиях. Лингвистика -- наука, а не анархия. А вы, уж простите, не Розенталь и не Лопатин, чтобы свою кодификацию предлагать в качестве безальтернативного правила.

Comment: Хорошо, я согласен, что следовало добавить, что обычно однородные, содержащие свои запятые, обособляют точкой с запятой, но это не обязательно. Я изменю свой ответ.

Comment: @Nektoid Это, кстати, более правильно в любом случае, ведь если точка с запятой обязательна при своих запятых, то пропадает возможность делить однородные на блоки.